# How should we be using length units in Polymer UIs to conform to Material Design specs?

Tags: html, css, polymer

The [Material Design Specification](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html) uses `dp` (device-independent pixels) units to describe length. This unit doesn't translate directly to pixels because it factors in pixel density which varies from device to device.

I've noticed in the polymer source code that most elements use `px` in place of `dp`, but wouldn't this be counter to the design spec since it doesn't take pixel density into account? Or is there some other magic going on that accommodates all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS pixels does actually take pixel density into account and doesn't always map to device pixels.

A CSS pixel should have a pixel density of around 96dpi at an arms length and thus maps to multiple device pixels on higher resolution displays.

You can read an in-depth description at http://inamidst.com/stuff/notes/csspx

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying that. What are the implications when using `px` as an analog for `dp`? I wonder if mobile devices use the "arms length" rule, as we don't typically hold mobile devices at arms length...

Comment: You can use http://viewportsizes.com/ to find out what "css resolution" different devices use. When developing for mobile devices, don't forget the viewport meta tag or else the device will use wrong viewport size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_basics